# Alexa custom skill sending LaunchRequest not IntentRequest

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am new to Alexa development so excuse my ignorance. Essentially I am trying to build a basic custom skill such that when I say *Alexa, kodi pause* it sends PauseTV intent to Lambda and when I say *Alexa, kodi play* it sends PlayTV intent to Lambda.

At the moment my skill is only ever sending a LaunchRequest, I cannot get it to send the specific intent. Below is my skill JSON:

```
{
"interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
        "invocationName": "kodi",
        "intents": [
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "PauseTV",
                "slots": [],
                "samples": [
                    "pause"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "PlayTV",
                "slots": [],
                "samples": [
                    "play"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "types": []
    }
}
```

Any assistance will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried requesting the skill in the format 'Alexa, ask kodi to play' ? I can't test this out right not but my first thought is that maybe when Alexa hears an invocation name without a key word like 'ask' or 'tell' she automatically handles it as a launch request.

Comment: Could be way off but I figured I'd throw that out their in case it proves helpful